# How can I fix this UPDATE PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql

// DETERMINE THE TABLE NAME

```
$update = "UPDATE table_abc SET client_notes=('$_POST[client_notes]') WHERE vendor_brand='brand123'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$update))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con,$update));
}
echo "Congrats! You've Added New Notes!";

mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

When I run this script it comes out successfully with no SQL error message, but in MySQL the row isnt updated and become blank instead.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: {$_POST[client_notes]}

Answer (score 1):

Do not wrap your values in parenthesis. `('$_POST[client_notes]')` should be `'$_POST['client_notes']'`

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174). You need to fix that *immediately*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update = "UPDATE table_abc SET client_notes='".$_POST[client_notes]."' WHERE vendor_brand='brand123'";
```

Replace the first line.